# Does a Split File Datasat need a correction for multiple comparison?

Tags: anova, spss, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

I searched already for similiar problems but couldn't find an answer.

I split the file in SPSS by a two-level between group variable (sequence) and then want to perform two ANOVAS on each of those splitted parts. Do I need a correction of significance level as a result of multiple comparison problem? Like Bonferroni? Oder isn't it multiple cmparison because I do the two tests on seperate data?

Thanks so much! 
Ralf